# Nuxt app can't detect device when reloading in dynamic routes

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, contentful

I'm developing Nuxt SSR app and using `@nuxtjs/device` to detect user device to change layout depends on the device.

My problem is that I can't detect user device when I reload in dynamic routes like `article/:id`.
`generate` in `nuxt.config.js` is like this.

```json
  generate: {
    async routes() {
      const client = contentful.createClient({
        space: config.CTF_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: config.CTF_CDA_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      })
      const entries = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: config.CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID,
      })
      return [
        ...entries.items.map((entry) => {
          return {
            route: `article/${entry.fields.slug}`,
            payload: entry,
          }
        }),
      ]
    },
  },
```

How should I solve this?

By the way, I can get article data when I reload in dynamic routes because I set payload.